# How do you hide the keypad on activity change or when edit text is not enabled?

Tags: java, android

How do you hide the keypad?

I'm currently using the following code to hide the keypad.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
   Window window = getWindow();
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: You may want to consider going back and accepting answers to questions that you found helpful.  People in the community are much more likely to help if you accept correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea for hiding the soft keyboard. You could probably use the SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN flag instead of the ALWAYS_HIDDEN one, this would allow it so it will re-open when the user clicks in the EditText without the need to call setSoftInputMode() again.